# Error "void value not ignored as it ought to be" in C programming

Tags: c

This is a part in my code:

```
Type* compileExpression2(void) {
    Type* type1;
    Type* type2;
    type1 = compileTerm();
    type2 = compileExpression3();
}

Type* compileExpression3(void) {
    Type* type1;
    return type1;
}

Type* compileTerm(void) {
    // TODO: check type of Term2
    Type* type;
    type = compileFactor();
    compileTerm2();
    return type;
}
```

I used Code::Blocks to build it and it returned this error:

> void value not ignored as it ought to be

at the line:

```
type2 = compileExpression3();
```

Please tell me why.

---

Thanks you very much for all your answers.
I've found out my problem.

Is is in my include file, compileExpression3 had been declared as "void compileExpression3(void);"

Comment: What is Type? And is the forward declaration for compileExpression3 the same as the implementation?

Comment: You btw need to fix that `compileExpression2` doesn't return any value.

Comment: Thanks you very much for all your answer.
I've find out my problem.

Is is in my include file, compileExpression3 had been declared as "void compileExpression3(void);"

Answer (score 3):

By elimination, it's likely `compileTerm` returns `void`.

#### EDIT

You added `compileTerm` but now `compileFactor` is missing.

Comment: This is compileTerm function: Type* compileTerm(void) {
  Type* type;

  type = compileFactor();
  compileTerm2();

  return type;
}

Comment: @hnimnart Why don't you post all your code ? Include `Type2`.

Comment: @cnicutar: Just added that method.

Comment: @hnimnart I can, but I won't do it if you don't show any effort.

Comment: @cnicutar: how can i do that? send you via email?

Comment: @hnimnart No! Add the smallest example that exhibits your problem to the question.

Comment: Thanks you very much for all your answer. I've found out my problem.

Comment: Is is in my include file, compileExpression3 had been declared as "void compileExpression3(void);"